# what is the difference between "./command" and "bash command"

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have simple bash script file, it contains only one line:

```
rvm gemset use --create 2.0.0@PRJ_NAME
```

If I run this script with:

```
./scriptname.sh
```

I get a well-known error message from RVM

```
RVM is not a function, select.....
```

but if I run the script with

```
bash scriptname.sh
```

everything is ok.

Can someone explain the difference to me?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your `.bashrc` that set rvm environment variables?

Comment: Maybe you should add #!/bin/bash in the beginning of your script!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a BIG difference.

Lets take the following script called testscript (configured to use /bin/ksh as you see in the hashbang):

```
#!/bin/ksh
#im testscript
cd /proc/$$
file exe
```

First lets execute it with ./:

```
$ ./testscript
exe: symbolic link to /bin/ksh93
```

Now calling bash:

```
$ bash testscript
exe: symbolic link to /bin/bash
```

Do you see the difference? The interpreter used by the script changed in the second command, so if the script depends in some **ksh** specific code it will be broken, and in other way if the scripts depends on **bash** specific code, then will broke it with the first command.

Other test you can do is to echo $PATH in the two different cases of execution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @luciano-andress-martini but my question is slightly different.
On my script I do not have any hashbang, is just one pure line. In this case the interpreter is not the difference. It must be something else. Something about subshell maybe?

Comment: So maybe is that your problem, when you not use hashbang, your current command shell will be used instead of bash (specially if bash is not the default), type ps -A | grep $$ to see what you're using and when you use bash you corrected the problem, but if your believe that bash is really the default shell in your console, consider using hashbang because your console bash can have some unexpected environment for programming.